# Fail to start a mono site with Apache2, 404 error with mod_mono

Tags: asp.net, apache, mono, monodevelop, xsp4

My home system is an Ubuntu 13.4 (upgraded from 12.10) desktop system, where I do some development, mainly in PHP, and I have Apache installed and working fine.

I need to do some development in ASP.NET and I installed MonoDevelop, as well as an XSP server.  From MonoDevelop I can launch XSP, which serves at port 8080 (localhost:8080).  This is okay during a development session, but for some reason XSP seem to be timed out, and my router doesn't serve port 8080; aditionally, XSP only serves one mono project at a time.

I have attempted to configure a virtual host with Apache, but it is not working.  I get 404 errors both for static files, aspx files and nonexistent files.

My vhost configruation is as following:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.net
    ServerName  myproject.local
    ServerAlias myproject.mydomain.net

    DocumentRoot    /home/myuser/source/myproject/myproject
    <Directory /home/myuser/source/myproject/myproject>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        SetHandler  mono
        DirectoryIndex  Default.aspx index.aspx index.html
    </Directory>

    LogLevel    debug
    ErrorLog    /var/www/vhosts/myproject/log/error.log
    CustomLog   /var/www/vhosts/myproject/log/access.log combined
</virtualhost>
```

Looking at the error log, I find the following messages:

```
[Mon Oct 07 00:42:45 2013] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 127.0.0.1] Zlib: Compressed 279 to 214 : URL /
[Mon Oct 07 00:43:00 2013] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 127.0.0.1] Zlib: Compressed 291 to 223 : URL /Default.aspx
[Mon Oct 07 00:43:04 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script '/home/myuser/source/myproject/myproject/Default.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Oct 07 00:43:04 2013] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 127.0.0.1] Zlib: Compressed 290 to 222 : URL /Default.php
[Mon Oct 07 00:43:14 2013] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 127.0.0.1] Zlib: Compressed 292 to 222 : URL /Template.css
[Wed Oct 09 12:36:00 2013] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 127.0.0.1] Zlib: Compressed 290 to 221 : URL /favicon.ico
```

The files `Default.php` and `favicon.ico` do not exist, the other files `Default.aspx` and `Template.css` do exist.

Thank you in advance.

---

### Update

I missed a part of the configuration: the `webapp` file.  I added to `/etc/mono-server4/debiab.webapp` to add the project.

```
<apps>
<web-application>
    <name>myproject</name>
    <vhost>myproject</vhost>
    <vport>80</vport>
    <vpath>/</vpath>
    <path>/home/myuser/source/myproject/myproject/</path>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</web-application>
</apps>
```

Now it works!

---

*Now, I cannot make it work for virtual directories for different apps.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my original question was answered by including the web application in the `.webapp` file in the `/etc/mono-server` directory.  During the process I decided to try using only one virtual host for all related Mono/ASP projects, so I came to the following configuration for virtual directories (alias).

The `mytestsite.local` virtual host (at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and linked at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`)

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@interlecto.net
    ServerName  mytestsite.local
    ServerAlias mytestsite.mydomain.net *.mytestsite.mydomain.net

    MonoAutoApplication disabled
    AddHandler  mono    .aspx .ascx .asax .ashx .config .cs .asmx .axd

    DocumentRoot    /var/www/vhosts/mytestsite/root
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/mytestsite/root>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex  Default.aspx index.aspx index.html

    Alias   /myproject  "/home/myuser/source/myproject/myproject"
    Alias   /othertest  "/home/myuser/source/othertest/othertest"
    MonoApplications    default "/myproject:/home/myuser/source/myproject/myproject,/othertest:/home/myuser/source/othertest/othertest"

    <Location /myproject>
        SetHandler  mono
    </location>
    <Location /othertest>
        SetHandler  mono
    </location>

    <Directory /home/myuser/source/myproject/myproject>
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/myuser/source/othertest/othertest>
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel    debug
    ErrorLog    /var/www/vhosts/mytestsite/log/error.log
    CustomLog   /var/www/vhosts/mytestsite/log/access.log combined
</virtualhost>
```

The `debian.webapp` file (at `/etc/mono-server4/`)

```
<apps>
    <web-application>
        <name>My Project</name>
        <vpath>/myproject</vpath>
        <path>/home/myuser/source/myproject/myproject</path>
        <vhost>mytestsite.local</vhost>
    </web-application>
    <web-application>
        <name>Other Test</name>
        <vpath>/othertest</vpath>
        <path>/home/myuser/source/othertest/othertest</path>
        <vhost>mytestsite.local</vhost>
    </web-application>
</apps>
```

At my Virtual Host root (`/var/www/vhosts/mytestsite/root/`) I have a simple `index.html` file allowing me to choose which test.

So now I have Mono (mod_mono for ASP.NET) working on a couple of virtual directories on a virtual host on Apache on Ubuntu.